# Install application dependencies/DLLs using Inno Setup

Tags: windows, qt, dll, inno-setup

I have compiled one application, and I have to deploy it. So, I have the application executable and some dynamic libraries. Some from Qt and others.

I need to create an installer which installs my application and its dependencies.

Of course, I was "googleing" but I am not clear at all how to do it. I will be grateful, if someone could to tell me how to do it.

I am working with Windows 10 64bits. I would like to place that dependencies inside of one folder inside of the application folder.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the DLLs do not need any kind of registration, just deploy them to the target machine to the same directory structure as you have on your development machine.

A trivial example:

```
[Files]
Source: "C:\MyProject\release\MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "C:\MyProject\release\Qt\*.dll"; DestDir: "{app}\Qt"
```